# How to use multiple artifacts targeting different branches to run on single stage in DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

[image: _CI_Dev atfifact when build branch is B1]How to use multiple artifacts targeting different branches to run on single stage in devops?
Will artifact filters work if it is included with specific branch so that only those artifacts will be picked up?
The reason to use single stage is because the tasks are common across branches

Similarly, _CI_QA artifact when build branch is B2.

So, all artifact filters are added in single pre-deployment condition and only those need to be picked which matches build branch

Comment: I'm no sure what you mean. Do you want to use at the same time artifacts from different branches? Do you have some code? Can you share?

Comment: yes, I want to use artifacts from different branches at same time

Comment: Sorry, to be sure. The same artifact but from different branches? Or different artifacts from different branches? Artifacts are produced by the one pipeline, right?

Comment: Yes, different artifact from different branches. Each artifact is produced by one pipeline only

Comment: And you use classic releases right?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej Yes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup generic stage pipeline for all environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65317365/how-to-setup-generic-stage-pipeline-for-all-environments)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is two artifacts definitions linked actually to the same pipeline/build

[image]

First:

[image]

And Second:

[image]

Then artifact filter per each artifact (step optional - if you want to have automatic releases)

[image]

[image]

Then on job definition you need to define what artifact you want to get:

[image]

Here you define what version of artifact should be taken:

[image]

[image]

Another approach is actually to use download artifact step:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have artifacts linked to different builds. For example, _CI_Dev which targets Dev branch and _CI_QA which targets QA branch. I added both these artifacts to list of artifacts in pipeline. In this scenario, will I need multiple stages like Dev and QA to run pipeline specific to artifact based on artifact filter? Also, I need to add gates and approvals only for QA branch