# How to setup generic stage pipeline for all environments?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I have multiple artifacts for each branch. Continuous deployment trigger is enabled For Dev: _CI_Dev For QA: _CI_QA For Staging: _CI_RC

I want to setup a common stage (since the tasks are same across environments) which should identify the source branch and use corresponding artifacts.

How to add approval and gates only for QA and staging?
How do I identify the source branch which triggered the tasks (for a job)? Should I run a powershell script to setup source branch value in variable to be used in tasks?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How to add approval and gates only for QA and staging? How do I identify the source branch which triggered the tasks (for a job)? Should I run a powershell script to setup source branch value in variable to be used in tasks?

I am afraid we could not add approval and gates only for `QA` and `staging`, if we want enable `Continuous deployment trigger` for all artifact sources.

That because approval and gates **currently do not have separate filters**, they rely on the option `Artifact filters`:

[image]

However, if we set the `Artifact filters` for `QA` and `staging`, it will filter out builds from `Dev: _CI_Dev`. Obviously this is not in line with our expectations.

To resolve this issue, the easiest way is to clone the current stage (*Although it can't exactly what you originally expected to use one stage, this is currently the best solution.*), it will also clone all tasks in that stage. changing `Select trigger` from `stage` to `release` and set the `Artifact filters` for `QA` and `staging`:

[image]

**Note:** Do not forget to add Artifact filters for `Dev: _CI_Dev` to the previous stage.

Comment: Can this be achieved using YAML?

Comment: @user3441903, Not yet at this moment. Check the comment in this user voice: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/629260/specify-manual-stages-in-multi-stage-yaml-pipeline.html?childToView=1078595#comment-1078595. To achieve this in YAML, we may need to write scripts just like you said to determine the source of build artifacts to set the conditions of the deploy stage.

Comment: But how do I view the release pipeline in YAML?

Comment: @user3441903, Azure devops define your multi-stage for release pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops

Comment: @user3441903, How about this issue now? Does the answer resolved your question?

Comment: No. I am looking for single stage pipeline for all branches with gates and approval for specific branch. Can I get a sample approach to do in YAML?

Comment: @user3441903, Just I explained it in my answer, you could not do this single stage pipeline for all branches with gates and approval for specific branch. For YAML, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass